# How to make SharePoint solution independent from browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, sharepoint-online, web-parts

The solution, that involves webpart, lists, html, javascript runs well in Microsoft Edge, but it does not work properly in IE11. Please advise if you have encountered same problem

Comment: Can you provide some more context in your question re: "the solution" or provide some more explicit behaviors when it "does not work properly in IE11", i.e., does the page not render, only portions of the page render, etc.

Comment: Do you meet any error in IE11 browser, can you explain more detail about "does not work properly in IE11"? Try to use F12 developer console tools to check whether there have some error message and use the Network tools to check whether the resource load success or not.